# Animejs absolute div transition to position of another div

Tags: javascript, css, animation, anime.js

I would like to animate three div's in a triangle path pattern so they are kind of looping in a triangle from corner to corner. I can't seem to make it to work. Something Is missing still.

Top corner element is going to the left corner but is not placing itself exactly at the position of the left corner but lacking like few pixels.

https://jsfiddle.net/nj1c2L8a/15/

```js
const el1 = document.querySelector('.el1').getBoundingClientRect()
const el2 = document.querySelector('.el2').getBoundingClientRect()
const el3 = document.querySelector('.el3').getBoundingClientRect()

anime({
          targets: '.el1',
      top: el2.top,
      left: el1.left - el2.left,
      delay: () => 1000,
      loop: false,
      easing: 'linear',
});
```

```css
body {
  background: black;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.el1 {
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
  top: 30%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.el2 {
  position: absolute;
  background: green;
  top: 70%;
  left: 15%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.el3 {
  position: absolute;
  background: blue;
  top: 70%;
  left: 85%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/3.2.1/anime.min.js"></script>
<div class='el1'>ELEMENT 1</div>
<div class='el2'>ELEMENT 2</div>
<div class='el3'>ELEMENT 3</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is caused by `transform` style which is applied to all elements.

Because of percentage values the transformation is based on size of each element and is different for `el1` and `el2`, etc. See [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform#formal_definition):

> Percentages:  refer to the size of bounding box

I also fixed JS to set `left: el2.left`, so after animation `el1` will take the place of `el2`.

```js
const el1 = document.querySelector('.el1').getBoundingClientRect()
const el2 = document.querySelector('.el2').getBoundingClientRect()
const el3 = document.querySelector('.el3').getBoundingClientRect()

anime({
          targets: '.el1',
      top: el2.top,
      left: el2.left,
      delay: () => 1000,
      loop: false,
      easing: 'linear',
});
```

```css
body {
  background: black;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.el1 {
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
  top: 30%;
  left: 50%;
}

.el2 {
  position: absolute;
  background: green;
  top: 70%;
  left: 15%;
}

.el3 {
  position: absolute;
  background: blue;
  top: 70%;
  left: 85%;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/3.2.1/anime.min.js"></script>
<div class='el1'>ELEMENT 1</div>
<div class='el2'>ELEMENT 2</div>
<div class='el3'>ELEMENT 3</div>
```